# Facebook API - How to retrieve a users timeline?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, posts, facebook-timeline

I can't find out how to get the content displayed on a users profile from the Facebook API. It's easy to get all statuses or so but then the photos isn't included...

I simply want to get all posts (including photos, check-ins etc.)  that is shown on a user's profile on facebook.com and I want them in the same order.

I assume this is possible to do through the API, would seem strange to me otherwise, so I'm wondering; how is this done?

Comment: you would need "read_stream", and that permission will only get approved for platforms without a native facebook experience (like smart TVs, for example)

Comment: @luschn Alright, so what you're saying is that this is not possible for an iOS app?

Comment: nope. only if you create an app that is just for you (the app admin) only, because you only need to go through the review process if you want to make your app public. without approval, it will only work for users with a role in the app (admin, dev, tester).